# Listen to chages in contacts database from background service on android device

Tags: java, android, cordova

i am developing an app with phonegap 2.2. I have been able to implement a background service from https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService.

right now i want to be able to listen for changes in the contacts database such that when a change is detected, a function can run in the background service (Java Method).
How can this be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a content observer in your service and register that observer to listen for changes in contacts database.
Here is an example of contacts content observer:

```
ContactsContentObserver contentObserver = new ContactsContentObserver();
private class ContactsContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{
    public ContactsContentObserver()
    {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        // handle change received
    }
}
```

You can register the content observer in service onStart() method:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
```

And unregister it in service onDestroy() method:

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks alot, but also Is it possible to also register the content observer to detect changes  in the SIM card contacts database by changing the content URI to ` Uri.parse("content://icc/adn") `

Comment: @Akos I liked your solution but the service is going to be running all the time and thus content observer will also all time. So observer is not unregister.  Will this cause any issue